# Unable to Get more than 200 pages of Message Trace Data

Tags: powershell, office365

I am using powershell to get message trace data. I have read that the max. number of pages is 1000. But when I try to retrieve data, it stops after 200 pages. I get the below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QElbL.jpg)

This is the command i use:

Get-MessageTrace @gmtParams | Select-Object EndDate, FromIP, Index, MessageID, MessageTraceID, Organization, Received, RecipientAddress, SenderAddress, Size, StartDate, Subject, ToIP

I have declared the max. page size and page numbers too.

$pageSize = 5000

$maxPage = 1000

Is there anything that I can do from my end or does something need to be changed at the exchange online side?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/error-while-fetching-messagetrace-data-using-powershell/m-p/1173395) and [this](https://cynicalsys.com/2019/09/13/working-with-large-exchange-messages-traces-in-powershell/). These links talk about dealing with large exchange messages.

Comment: I am facing this error with only one day's data! I will try to break it into chunks. But the max page numbers should be 1000. I wonder why only 200 is possible.